# MySQL LIMIT within JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, subquery

I have a table `symbols` and `statistics` which are associated by 1:m association type, but I need to fetch only latest `statistics` for few `symbols`. for example
I need to get `statistics` for `symbols` which has stock symbol `ORCL, SNAP, MSFT`. With `JOIN` I get all `statistics` for these `symbols`, but I need only latest for each `symbol`. So I have tried this

```
SELECT `symbols`.`id`, `symbols`.`symbol`, `statistics`.`marketCapitalization` FROM `symbols` 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `s`.`companyId`, `s`.`marketCapitalization` FROM `company_key_statistics` AS `s`
    WHERE  `s`.`companyId` = `symbols`.`id` ORDER by `createdAt` DESC LIMIT 1
) AS `statistics` 

ON `symbols`.`id` = `statistics`.`companyId` 
WHERE `symbols`.`symbol` IN ('ORCL', 'SNAP');
```

Here I am joining subquery table, where I am ordering `statistics` of `symbol` by `createdAt` column which is my timestamp by descending order  and limiting it to get only first row, but unfortunately I found that, I am not allowed to access main query columns in subquery of `JOIN`.

So what is efficient way of solving this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What main columns do you need to access?  Do you mean symbols.symbol?

Comment: Hi, as you can see I already put it, but I got this `Unknown column 'symbols.id' in 'where clause'`, so I am not allowed to use main query columns in `JOIN`

Comment: you are.  there is no column symbols.id

Comment: I need to access to `symbols` associated `statistics` which is connected by  `symbols.id` and `company_key_statistics.id`

Comment: oh I see. I will post you how to do it.

Comment: Thanks!, I just added `symbols.id`, but again same error

Answer (score 0):

Try this mate:

```
SELECT `symbols`.`id`, `symbols`.`symbol`, 
    `company_key_statistics`.`marketCapitalization` FROM `symbols` 
LEFT JOIN `company_key_statistics` on 
    `company_key_statistics`.`companyId`= `symbols`.`id`
WHERE `symbols`.`symbol` IN ('ORCL', 'SNAP')
GROUP BY `symbols`.`symbol`
HAVING `company_key_statistics`.`createdAt` in (
     SELECT MAX(`company_key_statistics`.`createdAt`) 
     FROM `company_key_statistics`
     GROUP BY `company_key_statistics`.`companyId`
     )
```

Comment: with this, I will get only one row, which will be `SNAP` since it is last in array, but I need values for all my `symbols`

Comment: you limited whole query

Comment: @ArenHovsepyan ahh now I got you mate, one sec

Comment: Thank you, but I got this error `Unknown column 'company_key_statistics.createdAt' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'`, though there is `createdAt` column in my table

Comment: In my main select I have added ``company_key_statistics`.`createdAt`` column and after got this error `SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'finstead.symbols.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`, do you know what does this mean

Comment: I have disabled `only_full_group_by` mode, but unfortunately it gave me again one result of `SNAP`, instead of `SNAP` and `ORCL`, though I have all records for that

Comment: soz mate, I tried to help you out here, but can't recreate the problem for me to test out. alternatively you can rethink the problem and break down the query into smaller but simpler queries